# No module named "file1.py"; test1 is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to modularize my code and I'm having issues with it.

My folder is constructed like this:

```
code
   |_main.py
   |_test1
           |_calcA.py (which contains a method)
   |_test2
           |_calcB.py (which contains another method)
   |_test3
           |_calcC.py (which contains another method)
```

Now my main.py contains these lines:

```
import sys; import pprint
pprint.pprint(sys.path)
from test1.calccircle.py import calcA
from test2.calctriangle.py import calcB
from test3.calccarre.py import calcB
```

The following error comes:

> ImportError: No module named 'test1.calcA.py'; 'test1.calcA' is not a package

Comment: add `__init__.py` file to testX directories

Comment: @eyllanesc it doesn't change anything plus it's not needed with the python3

Comment: you don't need to specify .py while importing modules

Comment: test1.calccircle is enough

Comment: @Mufeed thank you it works !

Comment: Can I add it as a solution?

Comment: Yes you can. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to specify `.py` while importing modules. Python knows your modules are Python code only. So remove `.py` while importing modules in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Test1 is a folder or directory and you are trying to access it like a package.
If you want to access it that way you have to insert **init**.py file in your folder. And also you don't need to specify .py when importing!

Answer (score 1):

add `__init__.py` inside your directories

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

`from test1.calcA import calcA` where `calcA` can be a method.